# Using regex to extract holding company

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Given a string which follows the structure as-

```
" (subsidiary of <holding_company>) <post_>"
```

where

- *holding_company may contain alphabets & some special characters including brackets*
- *post_ may contain any character*

Example string: " google (subsidiary of alphabet (inc.)) xyz"

How to extract the holding company name using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression to extract that is as follows:

```
"subsidiary of\s+(.*)\)\s+\S+"
```

In **Python2** code, you'd do something like:

```
import re
regex = r"subsidiary of\s+(.*)\)\s+\S+"
test_str = "\" (subsidiary of <holding_company>) <post_>\""

m = re.search(regex, test_str)

if m:
  # if it found the pattern, the company name is in group(1)
  print m.group(1)
```

See it in action here: https://repl.it/repls/ShyFocusedInstructions#main.py

Comment: works perfectly! thanks...but could you please add some explanation on how group(1) is capturing the holding company?

Comment: That group method is great! The more I see if pythons re import, the more I like it.

Comment: @schwillr regular expressions have capturing groups that allow you to extract portions of the matched text. These groups are enclosed in parentheses, and in this case it's `(.*)`. There can be many groups, the first of which - group(0) - is the entire match. I would recommend you to read a better and deeper explanation online, for example [https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#module-re](the python documentation). Also, play online with the excellent [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This suld get you there :

```
(?<=\(subsidiary of)(.*)(?=\) )
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates capture groups for your holding company and post.
You may need to expand the regex to include additional special characters.
Here's the regex on regex101 if you need to expand it
https://regex101.com/r/xpVfqU/1

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import re

str=" (subsidiary of <holding_company>) <post_>"

holding_company=re.sub(r'\s\(subsidiary\ of\ ([\w<>]*)\)\s*(.*)', '\\1', str)
post=re.sub(r'\s\(subsidiary\ of\ ([\w<>]*)\)\s*(.*)', '\\2', str)

print(holding_company)
print(post)
```